# Converting MediaRecorder .3gpp to Byte and then retrieve back to .3gp not working

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder, bytearrayoutputstream

I am having a very weird issue with converting a 3gpp(origin) file to bytes and retrieving bytes back to 3gpp(2nd) file.

The 2nd 3gpp file is I can't play using MediaPlayer and neither can play in my computer when transferred into. Also, 2nd 3gpp file size is little less than origin 3gpp.

**1.  This is how I initialize MediaRecorder**

```
String voiceStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + getPackageName() + File.separator  + "media" + File.separator + "voices" + File.separator + "temp.3gpp";
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(voiceStoragePath);
```

**2. After Recording finished this is how I convert it to a byte array**

```
File file = new File(voiceStoragePath);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] b = new byte[1024];

for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(b)) != -1;) {
    bos.write(b, 0, readNum);
}

byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
```

**3. Now saving bytes into .3gpp file**

```
String voiceStoragePath2 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + getPackageName() + File.separator  + "media" + File.separator + "voices" + File.separator + "temp2.3gpp";
File path = new File(voiceStoragePath2);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
fos.write(bytes);
fos.close();
```

**4. Device File Explorer**

[image]

**5. Playing it using MediaPlayer**

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(outputFile);
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
```

**Log:E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)**

Answer (score 0):

Well, that happened. It was so obvious that I have to stop MediaRecorder **first** before I convert 3gpp into a byte array. Still can't believe how I missed that one.

```
mediaRecorder.stop();
mediaRecorder.release();
mediaRecorder = null;

byte[] bytes = convert(voiceStoragePath);
```